# What is the difference between "default initialization" (`new C`) and "value initialization" (`new C()`)?

Tags: c++, initialization

What's the difference between these two statements?

```
C *c1 = new C;
C *c2 = new C();
```

The situation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new) (*Michael Burr*'s answer):

> - `new C` - default-initializes C, which calls the default ctor.
> - `new C()` - value-initializes C, which calls the default ctor.

I don't understand the difference. What do the terms "default-initializes" and "value-initializes" mean? Can you give examples?

Comment: Ok, but what's the difference between _default-initializes_ and _value-initializes_ as Michael aswerd in the source question?

Comment: @Daros911 if `C` is a class/struct type, both syntaxes call its default constructor. But if `C` is a fundamental type, like `int`, then `new int` will leave the value of the `int` unspecified, but `new int()` will initialize the value of the `int` to 0. That is the difference

Comment: @RemyLebeau It'll also be uninitialized if the class/struct has a trivial constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you use objects that are "Trivially Constructible", which means types that don't really have a constructor and neither do its members/base classes (including built-in types like `int`, `double`). Let's have a look at an example:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    int val1;
    int val2;
};
```

Here `Foo` does not have a constructor. When we create an object of type `Foo`, we can leave its members initialized with indeterminate values. Here's how we do it:

```cpp
Foo* pf = new Foo;
```

Here `pf->val1` and `pf->val2` essentially have some garbage values.
We can also `zero-initialize` that object like so:

```cpp
Foo* pf = new Foo();
```

Here `pf->val1` and `pf->val2` are initialized with zero. If they had a different type, like a pointer, they would have a different value, like null-pointer.

If the object does have a default constructor, the two examples do exactly the same thing.